# updating docker image given changes to local filesystem

Tags: docker

I am trying to work out how I can update an existing image when I make changes to the local filesystem that was used to create the docker image. I thought that I could use docker commits to do that, but it seems that that allows you to change the image when there are changes to the filesystem on a running image?

```
 /app.py
```

build from file system

```
 sudo docker build -t app
```

now there are local changes to /app.py. How do I change the image app to reflect the changes to /app.py? right now I'm having to delete the old image and then create a new one.

```
sudo docker rmi app 
sudo docker build -t app
```

any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, there's no `running image`, only `running container`. Image is something deliverable in Docker way, you build your `image` and then start a `container` from it.

To your problem, I think you have mentioned your options:

1. Rebuild your image
2. Go inside a running container, make changes and `docker commit` it back. Personally I only use this way to fix a tiny problem or make a hotfix to my image if `docker build` takes a really long time.

Docker uses [union FS](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/glossary/#union-file-system) with [copy on write](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/glossary/#copy-on-write) to build image, which means if you want make a change to an image, you can't change it in-place, it'll create extra layer(s) to reflect your change(s), it'll just use the same image name in some cases. And from the perspective of delivery, I think it's totally OK to build a new image (with different tag) for each release, or even it should be done this way, that's why you have an `Dockerfile`, and images are not only something you start your container, they're actually versioned delivery artifacts and you can roll back to any version if you want/need. So I think your current solution is OK.

A few more words here: for local development and test, you can just mount your `/app.py` as a volume to your container when you start it, something like `docker run -v /path/to/host/app.py:/path/to/container/app.py your_base_image_to_run_app`, then anything you changed on your local FS to `app.py`, it'll reflect to the container. When you finish your job, build a new image.

Answer (score 0):

As per your current design Solution is to create new image and assign same tag.

Best solution is expose environment variables from docker image and use those variable to update app.py so that you don't need to change image every time.Only one image is sufficient.

Comment: so do you mean open the docker image file system and make the edits directly there?

Comment: You can always go into container and change file system and create new image from it,But it is not ideal way if change is based on same value or configuration. What i am saying is that if changes in image are frequent then use environment variables to incorporate  configuration related changes.Use those variables and update app.py file accordingly.